# Threejs change uvCoordinate

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to flip the texture of a mesh, then I changed the uv coordinate of the mesh, the first I call the function, it works. Then I want to flip it when I clicked the button and call the function, but it can't work, what's the matter?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set an update flag, but I don't think it's the right update flag. Try changing `group.getObjectByName("object_11").geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;` to `group.getObjectByName("object_11").geometry.attributes.uv.needsUpdate = true;`. You don't need to set the update flag for your vertices unless you alter the `position` attribute buffer.

Comment: Also, please post your code as code, not as a screenshot. You can still annotate it with comments (`// <----- comment`). The screenshot is hard to read and copy, which makes it hard to work with.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I work it out in your way,it should set group.getObjectByName("object_11").geometry.attributes.uv.ne‌​edsUpdate = true;,My English is poor,sorry,I will remember it.thank you very much